# Is there a way to create a local debug build of TensorFlow.js? Or publicly available non-minified version of it?

Tags: tensorflow.js

I specifically would like a version of tfjs-backend-wasm that has the function names intact if I attach a debugger / profiler. If it matters, hosting it with node locally.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you include a Javascript library using a script tag, you can follow the link to download the javascript file directly, creating a local copy. For instance, from

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-wasm/dist/tf-backend-wasm.js"></script>
```

Just go to [here](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-wasm/dist/tf-backend-wasm.js) and hit Ctrl+S to save a local copy.